# Proof of subspaces and vector spacecs

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Which of the following sets $W$ are subspaces of the given vector space
$V$ over the field $\Bbb F$?

(a) $V =\Bbb R^3, \Bbb F =\Bbb R , W = \{(a, b, c) \in\Bbb R^3|a^2 + b^2 = c^2\}$

(b) $V =M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$, $\Bbb F = \Bbb R$ , $W = \{AB|A\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)\}$
where $B$ is a fixed $k\times n$ matrix with real entries.

(c) $V = F(\Bbb R,\Bbb R), \ \Bbb F =\Bbb R, W =\{f|f(x)\geq 0, \text{for all} \ \ x\in\Bbb R\}$.

(d) $V = F(\Bbb R,\Bbb R), \ \Bbb F =\Bbb R, \ W =\{f|f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) \ \ \text{for all} \ \ x, y\in\Bbb R\}$.

I tried to prove b) showing $0\in W, cAB=(cA)(B)\in W$, and $AB+CD$ is also a $m\times n$ matrix with $A,C$ are $m\times k$ and $B,D$ are $k\times n$. Now I'm stuck with showing $AB+CD$ as a product of $2$ matrices.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Explain "obvious." Obviously yes or obviously no?

Comment: What does your notes or your textbook say to do to prove that a set W is or is not a subspace of V?

Are there any examples in your notes or your textbook similar to the problems you have to solve?

Comment: The textbook examples used properties of a subspace to prove it. (0∈W; c(x+y)∈W if x,y∈W).But I'm unsure about how to prove b).

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove (d) using the [one-step subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test).

Let $f,g\in W$ and let $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. Then
\begin{align*}
(f+\lambda\cdot g)(x+y)
&= f(x+y)+\lambda\cdot g(x+y) \\
&= f(x)+f(y)+\lambda\cdot g(x)+\lambda\cdot g(y) \\
&= (f+\lambda\cdot g)(x)+(f+\lambda\cdot g)(y)
\end{align*}
so $f+\lambda\cdot g\in W$. Hence $W$ is a subspace.

The one-step subspace test is the most efficient way to prove a subset is a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

$a):$ Let $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$ be vectors and assume $a^2+b^2=c^2$ 
 and $d^2+e^2=f^2$. Check, if the sum $(a+d,b+e,c+f)$ fulfills the
 condition $(a+d)^2+(b+e)^2=(c+f)^2$.

The vectors $(1/1/\sqrt{2})$ and $(3/4/5)$ provide a counter-example, so we have
 no subspace in $a)$.

Comment: I think, in $b),c)\ and\ d)$, we have subspaces, but I am not sure.